# Crystalreportviewer fails to load anything with no exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I am stuck in crystalreportviewer integrated in asp.net mvc4 razor view (using webform to display crystal report). Using IIS7.5, I've placed aspnet_client folder (from **C:\inetpub\wwwroot**) with full rights into my website's root as well as resolved the undefined bobj error.
Even after doing everything possible, I see this on crystalreportviewer with no errors in console.

[image]

This is in my aspx.cs page load event:

```
 ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
 string strRptPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports"), strReportName);
 rd.Load(strRptPath);
 rd.SetDataSource(source);
 CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
 CrystalReportViewer1.DisplayToolbar = true;
```

It loads the report document and set its datasource and reportsource of crystalreportviewer yet I don't see anything in browser.

Here is my aspx page (crystalreportviewer control):

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" DisplayToolbar="True" Height="100%" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" />
```

I have given up the hopes after 2 continuous days with no output, if you can please guide on something i'm doing wrong or any suggestion.

Comment: Please try with some dummy data? Is it coming blank? have you checked the datasource
?

Answer (score 0):

When you are in Visual Studio, and click on the properties of the Crystal Report, what is the value for "Build Action". Depending on how you are interacting with the report object, setting it to "Content" may help.

Also, to make troublshooting easier, use a simple report with no subreports. Here's the code I use which accounts for subreports and also setting the connection to all tables in the report.

```
        public static CrystalReportSource Crystal_SetDataSource(string reportName, object par1, object par2, object par3)
    {
        CrystalReportSource CrystalReportSource2 = new CrystalReportSource();

        CrystalReportSource2.CacheDuration = 10;

        CrystalReportSource2.Report.FileName = @"~\App_Pages\Secure\Reports\" + reportName;

        CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Database crDatabase = CrystalReportSource2.ReportDocument.Database;
        ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        crConnectionInfo.ServerName = server;
        crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = db;
        crConnectionInfo.UserID = crystalUser;
        crConnectionInfo.Password = pwd;
        crConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = false;


        // First we assign the connection to all tables in the main report
        TableLogOnInfo crTableLogOnInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table crTable in crDatabase.Tables)
        {
            crTableLogOnInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo;
            crTableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
            crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogOnInfo);
        }


        //SET DATASOURCE FOR EACH SUBREPORT IN REPORT
        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section section in CrystalReportSource2.ReportDocument.ReportDefinition.Sections)
        {
            // In each section we need to loop through all the reporting objects
            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportObject reportObject in section.ReportObjects)
            {
                if (reportObject.Kind == ReportObjectKind.SubreportObject)
                {
                    SubreportObject subReport = (SubreportObject)reportObject;
                    ReportDocument subDocument = subReport.OpenSubreport(subReport.SubreportName);

                    foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in subDocument.Database.Tables)
                    {
                        // Cache the logon info block
                        TableLogOnInfo logOnInfo = table.LogOnInfo;

                        // Set the connection
                        logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;

                        // Apply the connection to the table!
                        table.ApplyLogOnInfo(logOnInfo);
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        if (CrystalReportSource2.ReportDocument.DataSourceConnections.Count > 0)
            CrystalReportSource2.ReportDocument.DataSourceConnections[0].SetConnection(server, db, crystalUser, pwd);

        CrystalReportSource2.ReportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon(crystalUser, pwd, server, db);
        if (par1 != null)
            CrystalReportSource2.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue(0, par1);

        if (par2 != null)
            CrystalReportSource2.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue(1, par2);

        if (par3 != null)
            CrystalReportSource2.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue(2, par3);

        return CrystalReportSource2;
    }
```

Comment: I've tried changing the build action to content which was Embedded Resource previously but nothing changed. I have made up a simplest report possible with a dummy list as datasource and just one field on report. I don't even have a clue right now of what next can be done.

Comment: If i see the html through Inspect element in chrome, I see crystalreportviewer loading up an iframe with source set to as empty.html, Don't know why viewer doing that. Can you give anymore suggestions? I've added IIS_User/Network Service/Local Service in the permissions as well..

Comment: Is "Copy to Output Directory" set to "Always"?

Comment: OK another question just to clarify: when you run your aspx application locally, does the crystal report generate ok? Is this only a problem on the deployed application?

Comment: Yeah "Copy to Output Directory" set to always. No, its not even showing up locally. I get the same screen. (Attached Image):(

Comment: In Visual Studio, are you able to generate the report OK just by running the Crystal Designer?

Comment: I've a sample crystal reports project that I downloaded from here: [link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Using-Crystal-Report-in-bb0e6229) and surprisingly it compiles and executes successfully so it clearifies there isn't an issue setting up crystal reports on the machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68925/discussion-between-douglas-timms-and-ali-baig).